# Excel - Use index to find multiple of the same value and return multiple values from another column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two works sheets one which will hold the cook book instructions

[image: Functions list]

Then another where the user will type in the function name and all the steps from the sheet 2 will appear.

[image: Worksheet 1 where the user types a function in]

What I want to happen is when the user types in "Turn on oven" in the sheet it pulls every step from sheet 2 where the function name is Turn on oven. So it would look like the following:

[image]

Currently I'm trying with

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!B4:B7,SMALL(IF(Pr!C4=Sheet2!A4:A7,ROW(Sheet2!B4:B7)-3),ROW()-3)),"Nothing found")
```

Which only returns the first step from worksheet 2 unless I change the row index.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: I'm using Office 2016 and googlesheets.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can replicate your desired layout without VBA, or a rather complicated formula; which would probably break if you added a step in your table.

However, if you want to put the steps for each function into a single cell (with the steps separated by a newline, then, in **Sheets**, you can use, for example:

```
=JOIN(CHAR(10), FILTER(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$5,A2=Sheet2!$A$2:$A$5))
```

**Instructions**

[image]

**User Sheet**

[image]

***In Excel 2016***, which, if I recall correctly, has the `TEXTJOIN` function but does not have the `FILTER` function, try:

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,INDEX(tblSteps[Steps],AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(tblSteps[Function Name]=C4)*ROW(tblSteps) - ROW(tblSteps[#Headers]),ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1,1):INDEX($A:$A,COUNTIF(tblSteps[Function Name],C4))))))
```

IF you do not have dynamic arrays in your version of Excel, you may need to enter that with `ctrl+shift+enter` and/or use this variation:

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,INDEX(tblSteps[Steps],N(IF(1,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(tblSteps[Function Name]=C4)*ROW(tblSteps) - ROW(tblSteps[#Headers]),ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1,1):INDEX($A:$A,COUNTIF(tblSteps[Function Name],C4))))))))
```